# Store Google Chat History

Tags: gmail, chat, google-talk

I don't use Google Talk. When I am checking my mails in GMail, I use the built-in chat mechanism. I want to store the chat history. Is there any way to record the history in the background while I am chatting?

Comment: You are already using Google Talk without knowing it -- you just aren't using the Google Talk client application, but rather the web-based UI integrated into Gmail. The two are merely separate interfaces to the same Jabber/XMPP network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GMail has automatically recorded what you'd chat. Check [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=29289).
I'm not sure what you want to mean "store google chat history". You can even check your real-time chat history while chatting.

[image]